# How to save workbook to a new location without saving changes in the old one

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to SaveAs workbook in to a new location with macros enabled(.xlsm) without having the changes saved in old one.

In example i open original workbook, create a new sheet, then macro would save it to a new location without changing original file, so if i were to open the original file again later it is without the new sheet created before. All help is much appriciated

I am using this code to save a file, but it also saves changes in the original file.

```
Dim path As String
Dim name As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
name = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.name, ".xlsm", "")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & name & "_spreadcell", FileFormat:=52
```

My plans for future are to import sheets from another workbook and then save this new file to opened workbook location and not save changes in the original file. So if something gets messed up, the user could still use the original file again to import and create new workbook.

Best regards

Comment: That's basically what `SaveAs` does. It Saves File A as File B and opens File B afterwards without saving changes to File A. There's also `SaveCopyAs`, which saves a copy of File A as File B, but keeps File A open.

Comment: Okay thank you, i need to test this code more. I am very new to coding and many things are still complex for me to understand.

Comment: @horst Your comment is a valid answer.

Comment: okay.. i will try to be more educated in the future. i appriciate your input and i will try to google more before asking something like that. i usually never ask a question about stuff. i google a lot of times and if i really dont see posts that suit to me, then i ask it. i apologise for stupidid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented before:

That's basically what SaveAs does. It Saves File A as File B and opens File B afterwards without saving changes to File A. There's also SaveCopyAs, which saves a copy of File A as File B, but keeps File A open.

Comment: It really saves File A as File B and opens File B afterwards, but when i close file B and reopen file A again the changes in File A are still saved.